# Unit testing of azure function(timer trigger) with mongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure, unit-testing, azure-functions

I have one azure function which is deleting records from mongo database with certain condition. I need to write test case for that. Please guide me how that can be done.

**Function Code:**

```
public class DeleteRef
{
    private readonly IDelete _iDelete;
    public DeleteRef(IDelete Delete)
    {
        _iDelete = Delete;
    }
    
    [FunctionName("DeletionOperation")]
    public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */10 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
        _iDelete.CleardData();
    }
}
```

**Mongo Code:**

```
public  class CleardAllData : IDelete
{

 private readonly IMongoClient _mongoClient;
 
public CleardAllData(IMongoClient mongoClient)
{
   _mongoClient = mongoClient;
}

public void CleardData()
{
    var db = _mongoClient.GetDatabase("ABC");
    var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("XYZ");
    var filter = new FilterDefination<BsonDocument>(); // I have some filter condition
    var deleteResult = await collection.DeleteManyAsync(filter);
    var numrowsdeleted = deleteResult.DeletedCount;
} 
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48580332/unit-testing-remove-one-item-in-my-mock-database , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64302966/unit-tests-for-timer-triggered-azure-function-provide-test-data and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53816215/how-to-mock-mongodb-when-it-is-called-from-another-function

Answer (score 0):

**Please check if given references help to work around:**

- Here is the [article](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/unit-testing-azure-functions-in-isolated-environment?ref=morioh.com&utm_source=morioh.com) that will guide you the complete unit testing of Azure Functions with mocking database access.
- To implement Unit Test Cases in Azure Functions, you have to use some methods like NullLoggerfactory, ILogger Class, ListLogger and as we know that the Unit Test comprises of 3 parts basically which are ***Arrange the Code***, ***Act Part*** and ***Assert Part***.

For complete demo information regarding Unit Testing on Azure Functions in above sections format, Please visit this [article](https://sntnupl.com/azure-functions-testing-guide-p2).

**Please check these practical references regarding to Unit Tests in Azure Functions Timer Trigger and other triggers as well:**

1. [Unit Tests for timer triggered Azure Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64302966/unit-tests-for-timer-triggered-azure-function-provide-test-data)
2. [Unit testing app using node.js and azure functions with SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67473484/unit-testing-app-using-node-js-and-azure-functions-with-sql)
3. [Article 1](https://sharenol.com/guide/how-do-i-unit-test-azure-functions), [Article 2](https://www.ben-morris.com/writing-unit-tests-for-azure-functions-using-c/)